# Поиск в файлах 0x1F (Unit Separator) при помощи линукс утилит (напр., grep)

Tags: linux, файлы, grep

Не получается отыскать в файлах Unit Separator.

Пытался при помощи команды:

**grep -liE "\x1F" ./xml/file_bad.xml**

Подскажите как найти имена всех файлов в папке, которые содержат 0x1F (Unit Separator).

[image: Пример XML]

Comment: **1** можешь куда-то выложить файл с таким символом? **2** попробуй `\\x1F` **3** тебе только найти или ещё и заменить?

Comment: 1. Не вижу функции на stackoverflow как файл прикрепить. 2. grep -rli \\x1F ./file.xml не нашел спецсимвол. 3. Только найти имена или число имен где встречается такой символ.

Comment: ладно :) мы тебе уже накидали ответов

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Поиск

```
grep -rn -P '\x1f' /path/to/dir
```

Поиск + количество файлов

```
grep -rl -P '\x1f' /path/to/dir | wc -l
```

Замена

```
sed 's/\x1f/___/g' q > newq
```

Comment: Проверил. Все три варианта отлично сработали. Спасибо.

Comment: @fedor-sg, если ответ верный и результат тот, которые вы ожидали, отметьте его нажав на "галочку"

Answer (score 4):

Можно как-то так например:

```
grep -ralF "$(printf \\x1F)" /path/to/dir
```

Comment: На моем примере сработало. Спасибо.